# Cleanly downgrade Nativescript to 2.5

Tags: nativescript, downgrade

since I have some issues with my app (that worked perfectly in 2.5) after upgrading TNS to 3.0 (I used the barcode scanner and the Xing decoder plugins both), I have the need to bring back my environment exactly as it was before upgrade.

But I haven't find an official way to cleanly perform 2.5 downgrade.

Someone can help me ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Try the following steps:

```
npm uninstall -g nativescript

npm cache clean

npm i -g nativescript@2.5.0

remove node_modules platforms directory in your project

revert your package.json to the version before update to 3.0(angular, typescript versions...)

tns platform add android@2.5.0

tns platform add ios@2.5.0

tns run ios or android
```

You can also check this blog for further instructions http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=509